# Application getting crashed on playing some sound file on iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to play some music files on iPhone but after playing some files application getting crashed. It's random in nature and I am not getting any particular scenario can any one help me out on this?

My Code :

```
 [player stop];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",crr_PlayFile] ofType:@""]] error:nil];

    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

Is there any problem in my code.

Comment: Try and split up your code, this makes debugging easier. One line where you place the filename in a NSString and log this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to 
`[player release];
player = nil;` 
after your `[player stop]` call.